# Swift: Implementing collection view without collection view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I set up a CollectionView**Controller** and got things working pretty well and straight forward.

```
class CollectionController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    .
    .
    .
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        cell.myTitle.text = self.titles[indexPath.row]
        let imgName = "pic\(indexPath.row).jpg"
        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: imgName)

        return cell
    }
}
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Now I would like to do the same with only a `UICollectionView` (**not** `UICollectionViewController`). I implemented my Collection just the same but when I run my app no cells are being rendered.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
class CollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        cell.myTitle.text = self.titles[indexPath.row]
        let imgName = "pic\(indexPath.row).jpg"
        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: imgName)

        return cell
    }
}
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Do I need to implement some initialization in my `ViewController`? I assume I'm missing something minor here :(

*I am working with Storyboard, so my Cells etc are generated there and not by code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your view controller set as the collection view's delegate and data source?

You can do this from code like `collectionView.delegate = self` or from the storyboard by control-dragging between the view controller and the collection view.

Comment: thaaaanks, that was the issue :))

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this link:
http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/ 
The idea is that you need to register nib(if use xib for custom cell) or register class custom cell and cellidentifier